# What kind can be the function of artificial neurone?

Tags: neural-network

I almost have the whole thing structured in my head but I want to just confirm it.

We have a neural network with 3 layers.

1. We input the Xs and their weights Ws (We choose the Ws on random at the beginning).
2. The neurone SUMs the x*w for all inputs (or can there be different function in here and if yes why would we need it, in what scenario).
3. We pass the sum to the activation function and we pass the output of the function to the next the neurones in the next layer.
4. While training the network we use back-propagation (if we have a NN without hidden layers) and we wait for it to train.

So my question is the SUM function, can it be different and if yes why?

Also a quick question if I want to train a NN to solve a*x^2 +b*x+c=y and I have random values for x and the corresponding y what will be the design of the network? How many layers do I need?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Try rephrasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding 2).That's the more function more generally used, the nonlinear weighted sum, in its more general form is f(x) = sum(w*g(x)) where g(x) is another function. You can change f(x) and g(x) as well but I won't recommended unless you have  a good reason for that. 
You pass the result of that f(x) to an activation function. I advise you to read about the activation function available and why you would like to use one of another, maybe this will help you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35776/choice-of-neural-net-hidden-activation-function

For the number of hidden layers:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw

Depens on your data basically.

I think this question belong to another site like cross-validated.

Cheers!